# Is there a way other than AT Commands to call a phone number?

Tags: c#, android, winforms, at-command

I am using c# winforms and wondering if there is any possible way to call a phone number. and i am not willing to use AT commands because it demands Serial Port which my android phone does not give when i connect it to my pc!

Comment: "dial android phone from pc" on google returned a large number of results.

Comment: May be of use?: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/66533/make-phone-calls-using-a-computer-through-an-android-phone-both-connected-by-wi